# OpenSSL C example of AES-GCM using EVP interfaces

Tags: c, openssl, aes, aes-gcm

For AES-GCM encryption/decryption, I tried this, but it has a problem.

```
ctx     = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();

//Get the cipher.
cipher  = EVP_aes_128_gcm ();


#define     GCM_IV      "000000000000"
#define     GCM_ADD     "0000"
#define     TAG_SIZE    16
#define     ENC_SIZE    64


//Encrypt the data first.
//Set the cipher and context only.
retv    = EVP_EncryptInit (ctx, cipher, NULL, NULL);

//Set the nonce and tag sizes.
//Set IV length. [Optional for GCM].

retv    = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl (ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_IVLEN, strlen((const char *)GCM_IV), NULL);

//Now initialize the context with key and IV. 
retv    = EVP_EncryptInit (ctx, NULL, (const unsigned char *)keybuf, (const unsigned char *)GCM_IV);

//Add Additional associated data (AAD). [Optional for GCM]
retv    = EVP_EncryptUpdate (ctx, NULL, (int *)&enclen, (const unsigned char *)GCM_ADD, strlen(GCM_ADD));

//Now encrypt the data.
retv    = EVP_EncryptUpdate (ctx, (unsigned char *)encm, (int *)&enclen, (const unsigned char *)msg, _tcslen (msg) *sizeof(Char));

//Finalize.
retv    = EVP_EncryptFinal (ctx, (unsigned char *)encm + enclen, (int *)&enclen2);
enclen  += enclen2;


//Append authentication tag at the end.
retv    = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl (ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_GET_TAG, TAG_SIZE, (unsigned char *)encm + enclen);

//DECRYPTION PART
//Now Decryption of the data.
//Then decrypt the data.
//Set just cipher.
retv    = EVP_DecryptInit(ctx, cipher, NULL, NULL);

//Set Nonce size.
retv    = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl (ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_IVLEN, strlen((const char *)GCM_IV), NULL);

//Set Tag from the data.
retv    = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl (ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_TAG, TAG_SIZE, (unsigned char *)encm + enclen);

//Set key and IV (nonce).
retv    = EVP_DecryptInit (ctx, NULL, (const unsigned char*)keybuf, (const unsigned char *)GCM_IV);

//Add Additional associated data (AAD).
retv    = EVP_DecryptUpdate (ctx, NULL, (int *)&declen, (const unsigned char *)GCM_ADD,
                             strlen((const char *)GCM_ADD));

//Decrypt the data.
retv    = EVP_DecryptUpdate (ctx, decm, (int *)&declen, (const unsigned char *)encm, enclen);


//Finalize.
retv    = EVP_DecryptFinal (ctx, (unsigned char*)decm + declen, (int *)&declen2);
```

This code is working fine (with some modifications). It is encrypting and decrypting the message.
The problem is that when cipher text is modified before decryption, it still decrypts the text (however, wrong).
As per my understanding of authenticated encryption, in such cases, it should not decrypt the modified cipher texts.

Where am I wrong?
Can I get any suitable example of AES-GCM using EVP interfaces of OpenSSL?

Comment: FYI, your repeated calls to EVP_EncryptInit and EVP_DecryptInit will leak memory.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is an example to encrypt and decrypt 128 bytes every call to update for example:

```
  int howmany, dec_success, len;
  const EVP_CIPHER *cipher;
  switch(key_len)
  {
  case 128: cipher  = EVP_aes_128_gcm ();break;
  case 192: cipher  = EVP_aes_192_gcm ();break;
  case 256: cipher  = EVP_aes_256_gcm ();break;
  default:break;
  }
  // Encrypt
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
  EVP_EncryptInit (ctx, cipher, KEY, IV);
  EVP_EncryptUpdate (ctx, NULL, &howmany, AAD, aad_len);
  len = 0;
  while(len <= in_len-128)
  {
     EVP_EncryptUpdate (ctx, CIPHERTEXT+len, &howmany, PLAINTEXT+len, 128);
     len+=128;
  }
  EVP_EncryptUpdate (ctx, CIPHERTEXT+len, &howmany, PLAINTEXT+len, in_len - len);
  EVP_EncryptFinal (ctx, TAG, &howmany);
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl (ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_GET_TAG, 16, TAG);  
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
  // Decrypt
  ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();      
  EVP_DecryptInit (ctx, cipher, KEY, IV);
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl (ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_TAG, 16, ref_TAG);
  EVP_DecryptInit (ctx, NULL, KEY, IV);
  EVP_DecryptUpdate (ctx, NULL, &howmany, AAD, aad_len);
  len = 0;
  while(len <= in_len-128)
  {
     EVP_DecryptUpdate (ctx, decrypted_CT+len, &howmany, CIPHERTEXT+len, 128);
     len+=128;
  }
  EVP_DecryptUpdate (ctx, decrypted_CT+len, &howmany, CIPHERTEXT+len, in_len-len);
  dec_success = EVP_DecryptFinal (ctx, dec_TAG, &howmany);
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
```

In the end you should check that the value of dec_success is 1.
If you modify the CIPHERTEXT, before you decrypt it, you should get value of 0.

Comment: That seems very logical. Can you please give me an idea how is it being done internally while decryption.I understand it can be done if we have some digest expression containing the hash value(md5 etc) of original data but what if we don' t have any sort of information regarding the original data ?

Comment: Is it legal to set the tag using `EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_TAG` *after* the calls to `EVP_DecryptUpdate`, just before the call to `EVP_DecryptFinal`? Is there official documentation on this parameter somewhere?

Answer (score 15):

Answer edited for modernity:

You must check the return value from the call to EVP_DecryptFinal() (or EVP_DecryptFinal_ex()) in order to determine if you have successfully decrypted the ciphertext.

OpenSSL now provides a perfectly functional example of AES GCM, written in C. It even includes test vectors. You can find it here https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/demos/evp/aesgcm.c or search for "openssl evp aesgcm.c"

The original 5-year old question, and its accepted answer, show code that uses the EVP_*Init() and EVP_*Final() APIs. These have been deprecated and replaced by EVP_*Init_ex() and EVP_*Final_ex() "because they can reuse an existing context without allocating and freeing it up on each call." ([openssl citation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/EVP_EncryptInit_ex.html))

In my experience, if you are writing a wrapper function for these calls, **do not** call EVP_EncryptUpdate_ex() with NULL and 0 for the AAD. This could have changed in newer versions of OpenSSL but as of 2013 it caused encryption failure.

It is pretty far out of scope for this question but in case it helps anyone, here is a working iOS / Objective C implementation that uses the OpenSSL APIs.

```
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <openssl/ecdsa.h>
#include <openssl/obj_mac.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>

#define AES_256_KEY_LENGTH      32
#define AES_256_KEY_LENGTH_BITS 256
#define AES_256_IVEC_LENGTH     12
#define AES_256_GCM_TAG_LENGTH  16

// encrypt plaintext.
// key, ivec and tag buffers are required, aad is optional
// depending on your use, you may want to convert key, ivec, and tag to NSData/NSMutableData
+ (BOOL) aes256gcmEncrypt:(NSData*)plaintext
               ciphertext:(NSMutableData**)ciphertext
                      aad:(NSData*)aad
                      key:(const unsigned char*)key
                     ivec:(const unsigned char*)ivec
                      tag:(unsigned char*)tag {

    int status = 0;
    *ciphertext = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:[plaintext length]];
    if (! *ciphertext)
        return NO;

    // set up to Encrypt AES 256 GCM
    int numberOfBytes = 0;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    EVP_EncryptInit_ex (ctx, EVP_aes_256_gcm(), NULL, NULL, NULL);

    // set the key and ivec
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_IVLEN, AES_256_IVEC_LENGTH, NULL);
    EVP_EncryptInit_ex (ctx, NULL, NULL, key, ivec);

    // add optional AAD (Additional Auth Data)
    if (aad)
        status = EVP_EncryptUpdate( ctx, NULL, &numberOfBytes, [aad bytes], [aad length]);

    unsigned char * ctBytes = [*ciphertext mutableBytes];
    EVP_EncryptUpdate (ctx, ctBytes, &numberOfBytes, [plaintext bytes], (int)[plaintext length]);
    status = EVP_EncryptFinal_ex (ctx, ctBytes+numberOfBytes, &numberOfBytes);

    if (status && tag) {
        status = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl (ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_GET_TAG, AES_256_GCM_TAG_LENGTH, tag);
    }
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    return (status != 0); // OpenSSL uses 1 for success
}

// decrypt ciphertext.
// key, ivec and tag buffers are required, aad is optional
// depending on your use, you may want to convert key, ivec, and tag to NSData/NSMutableData
+ (BOOL) aes256gcmDecrypt:(NSData*)ciphertext
                plaintext:(NSMutableData**)plaintext
                      aad:(NSData*)aad
                      key:(const unsigned char *)key
                     ivec:(const unsigned char *)ivec
                      tag:(unsigned char *)tag {

    int status = 0;

    if (! ciphertext || !plaintext || !key || !ivec)
        return NO;

    *plaintext = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:[ciphertext length]];
    if (! *plaintext)
        return NO;

    // set up to Decrypt AES 256 GCM
    int numberOfBytes = 0;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    EVP_DecryptInit_ex (ctx, EVP_aes_256_gcm(), NULL, NULL, NULL);

    // set the key and ivec
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_IVLEN, AES_256_IVEC_LENGTH, NULL);
    status = EVP_DecryptInit_ex (ctx, NULL, NULL, key, ivec);

    // Set expected tag value. A restriction in OpenSSL 1.0.1c and earlier requires the tag before any AAD or ciphertext
    if (status && tag)
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_TAG, AES_256_GCM_TAG_LENGTH, tag);

    // add optional AAD (Additional Auth Data)
    if (aad)
        EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, NULL, &numberOfBytes, [aad bytes], [aad length]);

    status = EVP_DecryptUpdate (ctx, [*plaintext mutableBytes], &numberOfBytes, [ciphertext bytes], (int)[ciphertext length]);
    if (! status) {
        //DDLogError(@"aes256gcmDecrypt: EVP_DecryptUpdate failed");
        return NO;
    }
    EVP_DecryptFinal_ex (ctx, NULL, &numberOfBytes);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    return (status != 0); // OpenSSL uses 1 for success
}
```

Comment: Do you have that github code working with a file?
I'm having a hard time to make it work.

Comment: Your code appears to be incorrect. Where is a call to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl` with `EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_TAG`? Also see [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: @jww First, this is encryption, so the correctly pedantic question should be about EVP_CTRL_GCM_GET_TAG. Second, I also didn't show the call to EVP_EncryptFinal_ex and you aren't complaining about that! Third, I provided a link to fully functional sample code! This isn't gist, it is SO and I think answers should provide useful information, not just be blocks of code. However, I'm a nice person, so if you need it, here's a complete Encrypt and Decrypt implementation: https://gist.github.com/eliburke/24f06a1590d572e86a01504e1b38b27f

Comment: @Eli - You should place your code with your answer. As it stands, your code is on one site, and the notes for the code are on another site. You are missing details when citing APIs, but then you try to find safe harbor because they are only notes. Also see [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/173448) and [Are link-only answers poor practice?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65277/173448).

Comment: @jww jeez dude do you have nothing better to do than crap on answers from **4 years ago**? To recap: The question had an accepted answer. I had some additional information for a different platform/language, so I posted it. It even got a few upvotes, so it was useful to someone. And the code wasn't wrong, you just made a mistake. That's ok, it happens. Maybe if you want to throw stones, you should start by editing your entire history to meet your current standards, because I see plenty of 0 and negative ranked answers from 2011-2014, with lots of links and incomplete code snippets.

Comment: @EliBurke Thanks for this updated answer but after looking through a lot of answers including yours, the only one that confused me was the accepted answer. My question is pretty simple. If we have a large hex bytes array (say 1500B), should we call CipherUpdate multiple times or will the API take care of it? Do you assume that the number of bytes of plaintext/ result will fit within one call?
It's a little different from the Python versions.

Answer (score 7):

OpenSSL has a nice wiki page on using AES-GCM ciphers. Code examples are also provided. The link to the page is [Authenticated_Decryption_using_GCM_mode](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption#Authenticated_Decryption_using_GCM_mode)

I followed this wiki and worked out decryption for AES-GCM. Code segment is copied below

```
int decrypt(unsigned char *ciphertext, int ciphertext_len, unsigned char *aad,
    int aad_len, unsigned char *tag, unsigned char *key, unsigned char *iv,
    unsigned char *plaintext)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
    int len;
    int plaintext_len;
    int ret;

    /* Create and initialise the context */
    if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) handleErrors();

    /* Initialise the decryption operation. */
    if(!EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_gcm(), NULL, NULL, NULL))
        handleErrors();

    /* Set IV length. Not necessary if this is 12 bytes (96 bits) */
    if(!EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_IVLEN, 16, NULL))
        handleErrors();

    /* Initialise key and IV */
    if(!EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, NULL, NULL, key, iv)) handleErrors();

    /* Provide any AAD data. This can be called zero or more times as
     * required
     */
    if(!EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, NULL, &len, aad, aad_len))
        handleErrors();

    /* Provide the message to be decrypted, and obtain the plaintext output.
     * EVP_DecryptUpdate can be called multiple times if necessary
     */
    if(!EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plaintext, &len, ciphertext, ciphertext_len))
        handleErrors();
    plaintext_len = len;

    /* Set expected tag value. Works in OpenSSL 1.0.1d and later */
    if(!EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_TAG, 16, tag))
        handleErrors();

    /* Finalise the decryption. A positive return value indicates success,
     * anything else is a failure - the plaintext is not trustworthy.
     */
    ret = EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plaintext + len, &len);

    /* Clean up */
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

    if(ret > 0)
    {
        /* Success */
        plaintext_len += len;
        return plaintext_len;
    }
    else
    {
        /* Verify failed */
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Also, as people pointed out, you should check the value returned from EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(). If your cipher text is modified a bit, it still can be decrypted, but the final returning value will not be true, because the authentication tag (or the mac) can not be verified.

Answer (score 3):

OpenSSL is not responsible for authentication. You should check the return value of `EVP_DecryptFinal`. If it is 1 then the authentication TAG of the decrypted data, equals the TAG you provided.

If the tags are different, then you should discard the decrypted data as forged.
If the tags are equal, then the data is ok.

Because the authentication is incremental, and can take several calls to Update, the data must be decrypted before the authentication can be completed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you provide an example or code snippets?

Comment: When whole data is in one buffer, then I do not have problem. But my problem is that I have large data to encrypt which cannot be accommodated in a single buffer. I need multiple IO operations to read and write. Can you suggest how to achieve the behaviour in such scenario?

Comment: -1: GCM is an authenticated encryption mode. Authentication is built into the mode. OpenSSL will return an error if the data is tampered, or the tag (authentication tag) is tampered.

Comment: Don't you think that purpose should be done by some other hash functions like md5 to ensure if the cipher text has been modified before decryption ?