# OpenSSL Authenticated Encryption

Tags: encryption, cryptography, openssl, aes, aes-gcm

I'm trying to use OpenSSL for authenticated encryption. Specifically, I'm trying to use `AES-256-GCM` (or CCM).

However, when I run `openssl list-cipher-commands`, I don't see it. The only AES ciphers shown are these:

```
aes-128-cbc
aes-128-ecb
aes-192-cbc
aes-192-ecb
aes-256-cbc
aes-256-ecb
```

I'm on openssl 1.0.1e, so it should be supported.

Comment: Try `openssl list-cipher-algorithms`.

Comment: @onemouth Ah okay, thanks. Why is GCM not shown in the cipher commands though?

Comment: probably because you cannot use the ID as command by itself?

Comment: @onemouth, you may want to post that as an answer to make everybody happy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OpenSSL supports `aes-256-gcm` as an algorithm, but it does not support `aes-256-gcm` as a command tool. The difference is that you can enter `openssl aes-256-cbc` in the command line to encrypt something. On the other hand, there are no such `openssl aes-256-gcm` command line tool.

You can use the `EVP` interface to call `aes-256-gcm` algorithm, as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153009/openssl-c-example-of-aes-gcm-using-evp-interfaces) shows.

By the way, you may try to use `openssl enc aes-256-gcm` in the command line. That does not work either, because no `additional authenticated data` will be handled by the `enc` command. See more information [here](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/id-aes256-GCM-command-line-encrypt-decrypt-fail-td27187.html#a27190).