# Can AES-GCM tag be set after calling EVP_DecryptUpdate?

Tags: openssl, aes-gcm

In all the code snippets I see involving using OpenSSL EVP interfaces for AES-GCM ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13045182/1505451)), the code looks approximately like this:

```
EVP_DecryptInit(...);
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(..., EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_TAG, ...);
while (...) {
  EVP_DecryptUpdate(...);
}

success = EVP_DecryptFinal(...);
```

Is it legal to set the tag using `EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_TAG` *after* the calls to `EVP_DecryptUpdate`? This would be convenient for example if the incoming ciphertext is being streamed, and the tag is located at the end of the stream.

Related question: is `EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_TAG` officially documented somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it legal to set the tag using EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_TAG after the calls to EVP_DecryptUpdate? This would be convenient for example if the incoming ciphertext is being streamed, and the tag is located at the end of the stream.

Its hard to say at the moment, but I am guessing NO. From OpenSSL's wiki page [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption):

> The tag verify is performed when you call the final EVP_DecryptUpdate and is reflected by the return value: there is no call to `EVP_DecryptFinal`.

GCM is an online mode, meaning you can stream it. However, the EVP interfaces are generic and they support other authenticated encryption modes, like CCM. CCM mode requires the size of the tag in advance because its used to format the header. CCM is an offline mode because the size of the tag a plain text needs to be known in advance. I'm making the leap that CCM restricts all other similar modes.

Also, OpenSSL is a SSL/TLS library, and not a general purpose crypto library. TLS negotiates the cipher suite and tag length as part of the handshake protocol. TLS does not have the use case you describe, so there's no operational requirement for OpenSSL to support it.

Related, the "OpenSSL is a SSL/TLS library" is the reason some goodies are sometimes missing from the library. Its a governance issue.

---

> Related question: is EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_TAG officially documented somewhere?

This answer to this question is NO:

```
$ cd openssl-src
$ grep -IR EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_TAG *
include/openssl/evp.h:# define     EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_TAG      EVP_CTRL_AEAD_SET_TAG
$
```

***IF*** `EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_TAG` was documented, then you would see a hit with the file extension `*.pod`. The pod files are the sources for the man pages.

But there is some wiki documentation from above. Matt Caswell wrote it and he is one of the OpenSSL devs. Though the man pages are the official documentation, the wiki is just as good in this instance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the answer but I would like to share my investigation on this.

The example on openssl wiki page https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption shows this sequence:

```
EVP_DecryptUpdate(...);
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(..., EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_TAG, ...);
EVP_DecryptFinal(...);
```

So you may think it is legal but in my testing is only half works: when I set altered tag  the call to EVP_DecryptFinal_ex indicates an error (returns non 1) but subsequent call to ERR_print_errors_cb does not show any errors. Weird.